# Mesos's resource information when executing a docker image

Tags: mesos

I'm working on Mesos code, and become very confused about the resource needed for executing a docker image.

In, [`src/cli/execute.cpp: CommandScheduler::offers()`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L473),  it pulls out the resource from the task, and uses this resource information to check whether to accept or decline the offer.

However in CommandScheduler, I don't see anywhere the task's resource is updated. 
And in the [`main()`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L887) function, where a `CommandScheduler` object is create, I only see a docker-image-string used to create the task-info, still no explicit compute resource usage information.

I need this resource information (code level) explicitly. Could anyone help me to understand this point?
I'm working on Mesos 1.2 right now.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you are asking for? A taskInfo is passed by user with flags. TaskInfo is created in main based on input from program arguments. TaskInfo creation happen in `main()` where flags are read step by step. If task is passed then its reources are loaded https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L1133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. By default, the resource allocated is `cpus:1;mem:128`.
It's done by [flag default value for resources](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L204-L207)

```
add(&Flags::resources,
    "resources",
    "Resources for the command.",
    "cpus:1;mem:128");
```